# GitHub file changes between two branches in PR

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

Say there's three branches, a `master`, feature 1 branch, and a feature 2 branch.

I'm working on a feature 2 that relies on feature 1, so I merge the feature 1 branch to the feature 2 branch.

In the pull request, I want to merge feature 2 to master.
For feature 2, it adds all of the files changed from feature 1 to the "Files changed" tab.

If I merge feature 1 first, will those files changed disappear when I try to merge the feature 2 to master?
Or will the same files be merged twice?

I don't want to put too many conflicts in the merges or make someone code review the same files twice.

Comment: Seems like something you could try out yourself - create a repo, test out the behavior, then you'll find out!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a feature 2 that relies on feature 1, so I merge the feature 1 branch to the feature 2 branch

If would rather rebase `feature2` on top of `feature1`.

That way, when `feature1` is merged to `main` (through a PR -- Pull Request), none of `feature1` files/commits will be considered on `feature2` PR.

Comment: What could I do if I already merged feature 1 into the feature 2 branch? I tried rebasing but it doesn't get rid of the merge commit or the commits from the feature 1 branch

Comment: @a.sun I would reset the repository to a state before the merge, then try again, this time with a rebase.